# Rotate 360 panoramic image according to compass

Tags: android, virtual-reality, panoramas

I made a bunch of 360 panoramic images. The camera was always facing north, so every image has a certain point, where north is. It's the same point on all images (300 Pixel from the left).

I would like to load the images on android, and offset the image, so that north on the image, stays north when the user rotates the phone.

I've tried [VrPanoramaView](https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/android/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/pano/VrPanoramaView) from Google, it always resets the rotation of the image to the phone's current rotation.

Are there any out of the box solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://pannellum.org/ ?

The [API](https://pannellum.org/documentation/api/) allows you to get the North Offset of the image, and specify a horizontal offset when displaying.

Pannellum displays in a Canvas, so you can load it in an Android webview.

Comment: I would like to do it natively in Android.